# How to align the nodes of a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs

I am using the following codes to get my graph,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto, node distance=3cm, 
                    thick,main node/.style={font=\sffamily\large\bfseries$\bullet$}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [below  of=1] {3};
  \node[main node] (4) [below right of=1] {4};
  \node[main node] (5) [below of =3] {5}; 

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {$e_2$} (3)
    (2) edge node [left] {$e_1$} (1)
    (3) edge node [right] {$e_5$} (5)
    (4) edge [left] node[right] {$e_3$} (1)
    (5) edge node[left] {$e_4$} (2)
        edge node[right] {$e_6$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gave the result like this,

[image]

But I want the figure like,

[image]

### Here, the nodes are properly organised. How to do that?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302149/why-positioning-above-is-at-a-different-height-than-above-right

Answer (score 2):

With help of TikZ library `positioning` is this easy to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,quotes,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,auto, 
    node distance=2cm and 3cm, % changed
    thick,
    main node/.style={font=\sffamily\large\bfseries$\bullet$},
every edge node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}
                    ]
  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [below  left=of 1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [below=of 1] {3};
  \node[main node] (4) [below right=of 1] {4};
  \node[main node] (5) [below= of 3] {5};

  \draw
    (1) edge["$e_2$"] (3)
    (2) edge["$e_1$"] (1)
    (3) edge["$e_5$"] (5)
    (4) edge["$e_3$" '] (1)
    (5) edge["$e_4$"] (2)
        edge["$e_6$" '] (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Main differences in positioning is define `node distance=<vertical distance> and <horizontal distance>`, in your case `node distance=2cm and 3cm`. To youse `positioning` library you also need to change syntax for node placement. Correct one is for example `below  left=of 1` (see different position of `=`!).

I also take liberty and change a way to labeled path. With `quotes` library is more shorter.

Of course, this diagram you can draw on different, probably more efficient way as automaton with help of `automata` library. For instruction see section *41 Automata Drawing Library*, page 513 of TikZ manual (version 3.0.1a)